# How to find the value of N in a logarithmic series

Tags: logarithms

${\rm{log}}_2(1+p_1h_1)+{\rm{log}}_2(1+p_2h_2)+\cdots+{\rm{log}}_2(1+p_Nh_N)=NX$

Here $X$ and $h$ are known, but $N$ is an unknown value

I want to find the value of $N$

Please note that $p_1=p_2=\cdots=p_N$ and $p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_N=Y$, $Y$ is also known.

And $h_1=h_2=\cdots=h_N$

Comment: If indeed all $p$ and all $h$ are equal, please replace the indexed variables with just $p$ and $h$. It's just confusing otherwise.

Comment: Also, if all $p$ and all $h$ are equal, the product $p_i h_i$ can be replaced by a constant $q$.

Comment: @pew, thanks for your answer. Please note that I am restricted by the equation p_1+p_2+...+P_N=Y, Y is known....Can we track the problem if I replace p_1h_1=q_1?

Comment: If the $p$'s are all equal and known, and if $Y=p_1+\cdot+p_N$ is also known, then $Y=Np$, hence $N=Y/p$.  Are you sure you've specified correctly what's known, what's unknown, and which variables are equal to one another?

Comment: @BarryCipra, thanks for your comments. In this problem, individual p's are not known, only their summation is known.

Comment: You said all the $p$'s are equal after "Please note that..."

Comment: @RossMillikan, Yes, they are equal, i.e.. Y=Np. Both N and p are unknown!

Answer (score 1):

When $p_1=p_2=\cdots=p_N=p$ and $h_1=h_2=\cdots =h_N=h$, the first equation simplifies to $N\log_2(1+ph)=NX$, or just $\log_2(1+ph)=X$, and the relation with $Y$ becomes $Np=Y$, or $p=Y/N$.  Exponentiating both sides to get rid of the logarithm and substituting $Y/N$ for $p$ gives

$$1+{hY\over N}=2^X$$

which solves to

$$N={hY\over2^X-1}$$

One should note that the problem set-up implies that $N$ is a positive integer, so $h$, $Y$, and $X$ cannot be arbitrary real numbers for the solution to make sense.